# HttpClient TimeOut/Cancelled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nginx, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

When I post data Timeout/Cancelled exception is thrown (in Cent Os 7, server nginx) but it is perfectly fine when run on windows.

Is there a workaround for this? It works fine when I call api within same application.

Here is my complete error:

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFinishSendAsyncError(Exception e, CancellationTokenSource cts)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
at CardApp.Repository.Notifer.FCMSendNotification(NotificationRequest notification, String To) in C:\GitHub\CardApp\CardApp\Repository\Notifer.cs:line 59
```

Update: Problem is when we are posting to https enabled apis.. Post request to http works fine.. It is because of client side encryption problem..

Comment: If error raising only when you launch your service on nginx server, so may be problem with server configuration or access to it?

Comment: i thought about that, and added domain to white-list but still not working..

Comment: I think you must dig deeper to solve server configuration/accessing problem. Usually Timeout/Cancelled exceptions raising when server is not accessible for requests.

Comment: Timeouts occur because the *server* didn't respond in time. There's no default timeout, they have to be configured by the programmer (you). So what does the server do? Did it even receive the request? Did a firewall *block* the request perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because server was unable to ping the url. I had it fixed after contacting server people. I got to know about it after posting a curl..